# Can I completely disable sound card initialization/recognition?

Tags: dual-boot, sound, dell, soundcard, xps

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS 13 (9343) and I would like to avoid the well known issue of [having to double reboot because Windows uses I2S sound and Ubuntu uses HDA sound](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1551880/comments/12).

This is a major pain and I almost started using Fedora 25 because it initializes the sound card in I2S using Linux kernel 4.8. (Leaving no sound problems between Windows and Linux) This is *wonderful* but there are other issues with Fedora on this computer that keep pushing me to use Ubuntu 16.04.

So, I am thinking it would be easiest to **disable the sound card completely** in the hopes that it wouldn't initialize it at all and therefore I wouldn't have sound problems when I boot back into Windows.

What's the best way to do this, add every `snd` related thing to `blacklist.conf` ?

...or, to make me incredible happy, is there any way I can use I2S sound in Ubuntu 16.04 ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to disable the sound card initialization, but as you said Linux kernel 4.8 in Fedora 25 can initialize the sound card in I2S, why don't you install Linux kernel 4.8 on Ubuntu?

Reading from [glaubitz's reply #12 on Bug #1551880](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1551880),

> The only proper fix is to use I2S mode on Linux as well which requires
>   at least Linux kernel 4.8

The current stable Linux kernel is 4.9.5, you can follow [instructions on ubuntumaniac](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2017/01/update-to-linux-kernel-495-stable-on.html). Alternatively you can choose to [wait for a few days more till 2nd February 2017](https://fossbytes.com/ubuntu-16-04-2-second-point-release-date/) for release of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS which packs Linux kernel 4.8 inside.

Comment: Great idea, thank you!

I had tried to use Ubuntu 16.10 (to use the 4.8 kernel) but that still left me with the same problem of Ubuntu using HDA mode. I read that the Ubuntu version of the kernel added a flag to revert back to HDA audio... while the Arch Linux or Fedora versions do not.

Will this upgrade on Feb 2nd still include the modified kernel that puts the sound back to HDA mode?

Comment: UPDATE: I found out how to modify the Ubuntu kernel to initialize in I2S from [this helpful answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/875775/how-to-make-a-4-8-kernel-config-change-for-i2s-sound).